# What to do with unidentified potions?

Tags: the-witcher

I have unidentified potions in my inventory that I probably have randomly picked up during my quests, or maybe I made them myself by mixing wrong ingredients... I don't know for sure.

Is there a way to identify them? Or should I get rid by selling them?

Comment: What Vemonus said; also, I always drank them, keeping a bottle of White Honey in reach. Some potions' formulae are hard to acquire, but I noticed I could find, say, De Vries' potion quite easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a post in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/915112-the-witcher/43988679/481959255), there are two ways to identify what those unidentified potions are. Drinking the potion will identify it if it is a legitimate potion. Finding the formula for that potion if it is in your inventory will cause it to become identified as well.

> If you get the formula for an unknown potion currently in your inventory, it will change to what it is. If you make a potion that comes up as unknown, drink it and if its a legitimate potion such as something like wolverine or perfume, the recipe will show up.